# Fancybox + swf gallery. Not resizing between items

Tags: flash, fancybox

Please see here for example:
( banners > dizzee rascal > see more+ )
http://www.ok-hybrid.com/store/wip/index.html

As they are flicked through, I'd like each banner to show at the correct size.
As is, they are all showing at 728x90 - the dimensions of the 1st banner in the gallery.

I've used:

```
$("a.fancybox_swf").each(function(){
   var $a = $(this);
   var h = $a.data("height")
   var w = $a.data("width");
   $a.fancybox({

            'width' : w, 
            'height': h
```

and for the individual items:

```
<a class="fancybox_swf" data-width="728" data-height="90" href="swf/dizcash_728x90.swf" rel="diztong">+</a>
<a class="fancybox_swf" data-width="300" data-height="250" href="swf/dizcash_300x250.swf" rel="diztong">+</a>
<a class="fancybox_swf" data-width="728" data-height="90" href="swf/dizholiday_728x90.swf" rel="diztong">+</a>
<a class="fancybox_swf" data-width="300" data-height="250" href="swf/dizholiday_300x250.swf" rel="diztong">+</a>
```

Thanks for looking. Any help appreciated.
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a normal fancybox custom script and get the `width` and `height` with the `afterLoad` option like:

```
 $("a.fancybox_swf").fancybox({
  fitToView: false,
  afterLoad: function(){
   this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
   this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
  }
 }); // fancybox
```

Comment: Done! Sorry about that, new here. Thanks again for the help.